# Stop Pro-Guard from adding "compiled from:" to the classes

Tags: android, proguard

So iv'e been enabling Pro-Guard to a project and after building the apk i decompiled it to make sure Pro-Guard did he's job and notices that it adds, for example, to the BaseAdapter class -

> /* compiled from: BaseAdapter */

See picture -

[image]

Now I'm asking, doesn't it lose the point of the Pro-Guard if it says what class that was?

Is there any way to tell the Pro-Guard not to add this info line at all the classes?

My code where i added Pro-Guard -

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        shrinkResources true
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.somethingsomething
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any clue on it @ItayFeldman ?

Comment: Nope, had to leave it that way unfortunately :) @Tobliug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proguard is not adding this line.

```
/* compiled from: BaseAdapter */
```

The decompiler is doing mapping of obfuscated name with original name. You are seeing it as you might be using [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or online service like [this](http://%20http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)

You can try using [dex2jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/) and [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to look at decompiled code. This line will not be present there.

Make sure that 'proguard-rules.pro' file does not have following attributes in it.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile
```

If you add this statement no decompiler will be able make this mapping.

Comment: I don't have that attribute, but it still manages to get the name. What am I doing wrong?